# Write file only work on IOS Simulator, in real device lacks permission

Tags: flutter, file

I developed a simple recorder that creates temp files and writes my records. I use path_provider to get a getTemporaryDirectory and write just like the answer below.

[Flutter - delete directory failed (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70594198/flutter-delete-directory-failed-os-error-operation-not-permitted-errno-1)

Works fine on Android simulator, IOS simulator and Android device, but when running on an Iphone the OS said I have no permission to write.

[image]

I added the needed permissions and the issue persists, is there anything more that I have to do??

[image]

It only happens on a physical IOS device, an Iphone.

The problem is this two lines:
[image]